# Spring MVC - RequestMapping - Execute only if a parameter is not present

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm making a test and I'm not able to answer correctly the following question:

Modify the Spring MVC handler method to only run if the parameter Bill is not present:

@RequestMapping(value="/getQuote", [...])

The correct answer should be the following (negating the parametert Bill):

params = "!Bill"

and the complete annotation should be the following:

@RequestMapping(value="/getQuote", params = "!Bill")

But this doesn't result the correct answer.

Where Am I wrong?

Can you help me?

Thanks and Regards,
Vincenzo

Answer (score 0):

> `@RequestMapping(value="/getQuote", params = "!Bill")`

This looks fine to me. 
I assume you're doing some kind of online test/exam which may not handle whitespaces correctly. Try it without spaces between `params` and `="!Bill"`.